# How to asynchronously call a database with subrecords using LINQ?

Tags: linq, async-await, datacontext, c#-5.0, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 and want to make the following query fully asynchronous:

```
 await MyDataContext.ADbSet.
                     First(a => a.Something == "Something").
                     ASubCollection.
                     Select(x => new { x.SubCollectionId }).
                     ToListAsync();
```

This doesn't work, I believe due to `First()` returning the actual entity and access to `ASubCollection` being an `ICollection`, not an `IQueryable`.

I was able to work around this with the following code:

```
 await MyDataContext.ADbSet.
                     Where(a => a.Something == "Something").
                     SelectMany(a => a.ASubCollection).
                     Select(x => new { x.SubCollectionId }).
                     ToListAsync();
```

However, this seems "hacky" as I'm using a `Where(...)` when I should be using a `First()` as I know at compile time that there will be exactly one element satisfying the query. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @VladimirFrolov at what point? Please elaborate.

Comment: `.ADbSet.Where(a => a.Something == "Something").Take(1)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call to `First()` is a call that actually enumerates the underlying sequence and returns an entity instead of a `Task`. Thus `First()` won't work together with the `await`-keyword.

Your second solution is completely valid (and not "hacky" at all) in this context, because there is no need to add a limit to the generated database query, as the `Where(...)`-call will return exactly one element in this special case - with or without a limit in the query.

If the `Where`-call is likely to return multiple elements, or you simply want to ensure that there will be only the first element considered, inserting a call to `Take(1)` will bring the first element of the sequence, but still be an `IQueryable`:

```
await MyDataContext.ADbSet
                   .Where(a => a.Something == "Something")
                   .Take(1)
                   .SelectMany(a => a.ASubCollection)
                   .Select(x => new { x.SubCollectionId })
                   .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Well, this is what Joel Spolsky calls "leaking abstraction" :) Thanks for the info!

Comment: @DarkWanderer Seems you are right about that! :) For those who, like me, might wonder what "leaking abstraction" is all about, here's the link to Joel's blog: [The Law of Leaky Abstractions](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html)